# How many textviews it is OK to create on iPhone?

Tags: ios, resources

I am developing non-standard rich text view to display output of some other program. I found it is very easy to do by just adding loads of UITextView into ScrollView, and then set various properties for each label. Like text size, color, transparency etc, etc. Some of them could be clickable buttons.

But now the logical question, how  many TextViews iPhone can safely handle?

Of course, I can do some tests myself, (and will I do) but it might not be reliable, maybe someone knows better from experience or some documentation or calculations?
Maybe the question could be generalized to "how many views"? But I am interested mostly in TextViews so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to worry about the safe number of `UITextView` you can use. Because you know the screen of the iPhone is so small. Do you think you need so many `UITextView` on one screen that the iOS even can not handle?

Comment: The OP is talking about adding many to a scroll view. Screen height is irrelevant.